# Injectivity for an integral operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, integral-equations

Consider the operator
$$K:L^2(0,1)\rightarrow L^2(0,1) \\ u\rightarrow\int_0^1k(s,x)u(s)ds.$$
with $k\in L^2((0,1)\times(0,1)).$

I want to know under what assumption the kernel is reduced to zero. i.e. $\ker(K)={0}$.
I can say that if $k$  is a Green function for some differential operator this will be true. But what about the general case? Can we obtain a criteria for the injectivity by some expansion process on the $L^2$ basis?. Thank you.

Comment: Look into the Fredholm alternative and in particular Hilbert-Schmidt theory.

Comment: If $k∈ L^2$, then your operator is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, and thus compact. I think it implies that $\mathrm{Ker}(K) \neq \{0\} $